# WebStorm equivalent folder configurations as VSCode ".vscode" folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm, prettier

I have a repository with `prettier` package installed. I have configured the repository in VSCode to be formatted by Prettier with each save action on any file.

I want to do the same thing in WebStorm without any pre-manual action. Because at the moment, if I open the repository with WebStorm, in order to get auto-format by `prettier`, I need to manually configure it within the settings of WebStorm.

In VSCode, I created the file: `.vscode/settings.json`:

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
}
```

How can I make the same in WebStorm so I won't need to do it manually?

Comment: this can be only done in settings, there are no JSON files you can use to set up WebStorm preferences

Comment: @lena No equivalent in the .idea folder??

Answer (score 0):

You can add `prettier.xml` like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="PrettierConfiguration">
    <option name="myRunOnSave" value="true" />
    <option name="myRunOnReformat" value="true" />
  </component>
</project>
```

to the project `.idea` folder.
But the prettier package path is stored in `workspace.xml` that is huge and updated ofter... you can search for the `"prettierjs.PrettierConfiguration.Package"` key to see what this configuration looks like there